# React Native TouchableWithoutFeedback is not working

Tags: javascript, react-native

I create a component `DismissKeyboard`. TouchableWithoutFeedback wraps its children. When someone clicks outside of the component the keyboard is supposed to dismiss. What am I doing wrong?

DismissKeyboard.js

```
const DismissKeyboard = ({children}) => (
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback
    accessible={false}
    onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}
  >
    {children}
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
);
```

Wrapping my TextInput

```
<DismissKeyboard>
        <View style={styles.noteContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.noteTextInputStyling}
            multiline
            value={note}
            placeholder={'Tap to edit'}
            placeholderTextColor={globals.COLOR.textColor}
            onChangeText={(text) => {
              setNote(text);
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </DismissKeyboard>
```

What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using it like this:

```
const DismissKeyboard = ({children}) => (
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback
    accessible={false}
    onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}
  >
   <View>
    {children}
   </View>
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with a combination of `KeyboardAvoidingView` and `TouchableWithoutFeedback` like below. Be aware to use Keyboard.dismiss instead of Keyboard.dismiss()

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Keyboard, KeyboardAvoidingView, TouchableWithoutFeedback,
} from 'react-native';

const DismissKeyboard = ({ children }) => (
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={{ flex: 1 }} onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      {children}
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
);
```